# Are later references to Project Genesis?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, terraforming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Was project genesis ever revisted/used after Star Trek II/III?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/24377/was-project-genesis-ever-revisted-used-after-star-trek-ii-iii)

I just watched STII: The Wrath of Khan and STIII: The Search for Spock again after many years, in which Project Genesis is integral to the plot.

Are there are references to Project Genesis or similar technology later in the timeline (TNG, DS9 or VOY) ?

Comment: Oops, my bad -- exact duplicate.

Comment: Project Genesis was referenced once again in season 4 of TNG, when they sold it to the Ferengi as part of the Federation's restructuring for Chapter 11 bankruptcy.

Comment: Also mentioned in Star Trek STIV: The Journey Home (if you want a later TOS reference.

Comment: @ThePopMachine and yet google sent me here first, (potential) proof that duplicates still serve a useful purpose :-) (I'm trying to track down the reference to 1996 in [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/49137/what-skipped-test-on-genesis-would-have-detected-the-backwards-inserted-accelero?noredirect=1#comment159276_49137))

Comment: Ah! [Khan was the last of the tyrants to be overthrown, in 1996. Khan and over eighty of the "supermen" were condemned to die as war criminals. They however went unaccounted for, a fact the governments of the time did not disclose to the public in order to prevent panic. Rumors were later confirmed in the 23rd century that Khan and 84 of his followers had managed to flee the planet aboard an early sleeper ship, the SS Botany Bay.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eugenics_Wars)